# how can i use getch and ctr in c programming

Tags: c

hi everybody i need a help please i try to compiling the following code

```
int ctr=0;
clrscr();
while(ctr!=1)switch(getch()){
              case 77: printf("Right");
              break;
```

when i try i have this errors ,and when i try to add  i have the error file don't exist how can i do to use getch in my code

```
test.c:618:1: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘clrscr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
test.c:619:1: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘getch’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

NB:i work in ubuntu 13.04

Comment: `getch` and `clrscr` are part of the non standard lib `conio.h` (for windows)

Comment: You might want to read about [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: Use `ncurses` for ubuntu

Comment: so how can i use it in linux?? have you any idea please?

Answer (score 2):

These functions are both declared in `conio.h`, which is not part of any C standard. They were implemented by tradition in many DOS-based compilers. There is no platform-independent substitute for `clrscr()` -- you might use `system("clear")` instead. For `getch()`, the closest single-function replacement is `cin.get()` in C++. A better overall strategy would be to rewrite the code using the moderately portable [curses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library, which includes all the capabilities of `conio.h` and more.

Answer (score 0):

Function getch() is a part of "curses" library (see header curses.h). clrscr() can be replaced with erase() function from this library as well. [Link to header curses.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcurses/curses.h.html).

Answer (score 0):

> getch() function is included in conio.h library, but conio.h standard
>   library is not available in linux instead we can use curses.h header
>   file. curses.h contains definitions for screen handling and
>   optimisation functions.

**curses.h documentation**

> http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcurses/curses.h.html

**1. Installing curses.h in linux**

//For debian based linux distros

*sudo apt install -y  libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev*

//For fedora

*sudo yum install ncurses-devel*

**2. Compilling Program (my .c file name is getchDemo)**

*g++ -o outputFile getchDemo.c -lncurses*

**3. Running Program**

*./outputFile*

[image: sample program with output]